# can't Delete a foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have run this code to link the foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE episodes
ADD FOREIGN KEY (animes_id) REFERENCES animes (id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE,
```

And now I'm trying to delete the foreign key and is not working, I'm using this code:

```
ALTER TABLE episodes
DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_animes_id;
```

When I use it apears this error code **#1091**.

What do I need to delete the colum `animes_id`?

Thanks!

Comment: You only get the numeric code, not the corresponding informative text?

Comment: Error message for [1091](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html) is *Can't DROP '%s'; check that column/key exists*. I can't see the FK_animes_id name anywhere in your key creation statement, so they key probably does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to get foreign key constraint name from  SHOW CREATE table episodes. Because you have added foreign key while creating table. If you have added the same by using alter then at that time you might have given constraing name, what i mean to say is that ur giving costrnaint name which is not given by you.

SHOW CREATE table episodes
with that you can get constraint name, once u get the same u can easily delete it.

Comment: I use the code `SHOW CREATE table episodes` and this as apear                     [link](http://prntscr.com/eobo6l)